# Backbone 101 - Using JSON data with backbone

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm in the beginning stages of moving my application to the backbone framework.

I have some data that comes in as json from an ajax call

```
{f1:"f1_value", f2:"f2_value", f3:"f3_value"},
{f1:"f1_value", f2:"f2_value", f3:"f3_value"},
{f1:"f1_value", f2:"f2_value", f3:"f3_value"},
```

This data set always has 3 columns but may be as long as needed for each set as far as rows goes.

It is used to populate a div after processing it client side into HTML, which correlatively may extend down as far as needed.  I was planning on this data chunk representing one view in the framework.

```
<div id = "data_hold"></div>
```

How do I match this up to the framework:

```
    var ModelTest,
        CollectionTest,
        ViewTest;

    ModelTest = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });
    CollectionTest = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ModelTest
    }
    ViewTest = Backbone.View.extend({
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone 101:

```
var ModelTest,
    CollectionTest,
    ViewTest;

ModelTest = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

// associate your collection with a URL.  This is static here; it can be
// passed in as an option using the Collection's initialize function()
// instead.

CollectionTest = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ModelTest,
    url: 'http://localhost/my_json_source'
});

ViewTest = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Have a target to render into.  This can be an existing element, as  
    // here, or it can be dynamically generated and attached to the DOM
    // programattically.
    el: $('#data_hold'),

    // specify than when the collection is updated, call the local render
    // method.

    initialize: function(options) { 
        this.collection.bind('reset', _.bind(this.render, this));
    },

    // Empty the element, then append subsequent rows of the collection
    // to it as paragraphs.  The '_this = this' idiom allows us to access
    // the outside context (the View's context), since the each() call 
    // will create a new inner context.

    render: function() {
        var _this = this;
        this.$el.html('');
        this.collection.each(function(l) {
            _this.$el.append('<p>' + l.get('f2') + '</p>');
            });
    }
});

// initialize the collection and view, then fetch the collection, which
// will trigger the render after the collection has been updated.

$(function() {
    ct = new CollectionTest();
    vt = new ViewTest({collection: ct});
    ct.fetch();
});
```

Comment: Does the ViewTest constructor require an object literal, or could you just pass in ct?

Comment: It requires an object literal.  Views take a single argument, an "options" object.  It scans the object for the following elements, and incorporates them automatically into the view if they're found when instantiated: 'model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events.'  All other options, you have to handle yourself in `__initialize()__`.

I recommend reading the source code to Backbone.JS.  Jeremy writes awesomely clean and understandable code.  The signature and code path for View initialization will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) might be a better (or less zombie prone) choice than [`bind`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) with newer Backbones.

Comment: Yeah, and I'd love to do this in Coffeescript, where the fat arrow operator abstracts away entire layers of binding and the `_this=this` idiom.

Comment: I understand the structure of this...but what makes it "go". From the documentation ... http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch ... it appears Collection.fetch() will make it go.  Everything else is automatic - view updating etc.?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Read The Source, Luke.  When the collection fetch ends, it publishes a 'reset' event.  The view initializer subscribes to that event saying, "when that reset happens, render."  Magic.

It would be nice if it worked the other way, so when a view changes (via jQuery events, usually), the collection was changed automagically too.  There's a plug-in that does this, called Bacon, but I haven't played with it much.  The View's "events:" dispatcher still requires that we write the event handler the old-fashioned way, but it's getting better.

Comment: Normally I access my JSON data using an ajax post request.  This interface requires a url and the post data.  How do I get these two items in to the url property ... i.e. the             `xhr.send(data);` part, where does it go?